# How to write a t-sql statement to count the number of occurences of a flag in a particular grouping?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here is a sample of what my data will look like:

```
SELECT key1, key2, flag FROM mysegtable
```

Which will produce output like this:

```
key1  key2  flag
 1     1      A
 1     2      A
 1     3      B

 2     1      A
 2     2      A

 3     1      A
 3     1      B
```

Where key1 can be thought of as a key for a header table, and key1 + key2 is the key for a segment table. Header -> segment is a one to many connections. For each segment entry, there is an associated flag, A or B. I need to count the number of occurrences of all unique values A, B, ... and output whichever shows up the most often per key1. Further, I must be able to impose logic when the number of occurrences is the same.

So the output should be:

```
key1  flag
 1      A
 2      A
 3      B
```

Where B is given higher priority in ties.

My efforts so far were focused on selecting from my table for each flag occurrence, getting a count, and then doing a union on the results so that I would have a count for every key and flag value pair. From there I'm not sure how I can extract the highest occurrence flag per key, and impose my priority cases.

I appreciate any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most frequent value is called the "mode" in statistics.  Here is one method to calculate it:

```
select t.*
from (select key1, flag, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by key1 order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by key1, flag
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: The query worked out great! One thing I ended up adding, because I failed to mention it in the main post is the sorting by flag to non-standard sorting (not just A, B, C etc). My actual flags are IT, I, and D, in that order.  To support that I used a case statement in the first order by clause that assigns a numerical value to the flags.